# Hashtable update in WebService java

Tags: java, web-services, hashtable

I developed a simple distrusted system in Java RMI, now I have to change it to Web Services. I have a problem with my data structure:

`Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Records>> recordsTable;`

**it does not serialize/update my objects correctly.**

I'm clueless how to change my data structure to overcome such problem?

[Edited]

For simplicity, say I have this data structure:

`Hashtable<String, Integer> store = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();`

I have a buy() and display() service that is published. Initially I have 100 Apples in store, so when I buy() 10 apples it will print a result of 90 apples. **BUT** when I invoke display later it will print 100 apples.

So there is a serialization problem I have no idea how to fix that.

```
public class StoreServer{

Hashtable<String, Integer> store= new Hashtable<String, Integer>();

public StoreServer()
{
    store.put("Coffee", 20);
    store.put("Apple", 100);
    store.put("Banana", 50);
    display();
}

public String buy(String item, int quantity)
{
    if(store.containsKey(item))
    {
        int oldQuantity = store.get(item);
        int newQuantity;
        if(oldQuantity-quantity>=0)
        {
            newQuantity= oldQuantity -quantity;
            store.put(item, newQuantity);
            return quantity+" "+item+" were successfully purchased!\n" +

                    ("1. Coffee: "+store.get("Coffee")+"\n")+
                    ("2. Apples: "+store.get("Apple")+"\n")+
                    ("3. Bananas: "+store.get("Banana")+"\n")+
                    ("---------------------------\n");
        }
        else
        {
            return "error with your purchase";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "error with your purchase";
    }
}


public void display()
{
    System.out.println("------Store Inventory-----");
    System.out.println("1. Coffee: "+store.get("Coffee"));
    System.out.println("2. Apples: "+store.get("Apple"));
    System.out.println("3. Bananas: "+store.get("Banana"));
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
}}
```

Comment: Please post some code that reproduces the problem. Do `Records` implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface?

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I added a simple code of my problem

Comment: @bizmark No it doesn't. I edited my post using Hashtable of String and Integer and still gives a problem.

Comment: You might want to check how you save the HashTable state across threads/requests. Is it a static variable in one of your classes, is it recreated on each request, or...!?

Comment: @Grove I dont have threads now, but am just testing the functionality in WS. you can view the code, I updated it with the whole class.

Comment: what is ` inventory' - you load oldQuantity using this, but what is it?  And what do you mean by `publish`?  We can guess, but... what?

Comment: @sbk am sorry it was a typo, I meant store. Publish is when I create make the StoreServer as a web service that provides services as buy and display.

Answer (score 0):

Web Services use a stateless protocol. You need to set the store HashMap to static. 
Also, make sure it is a ConcurrentHashMap because it may be accessed by multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: I tried with static keyword and still same, doesn't update correctly.

Comment: post the rest of the code, then (ie. the relevant server code)